# How to convert String to Integer array and back in JAVA

Tags: java, string, serialization, integer

I want to deserialize String into int[] array and back. I try something like this

```
public static int[] getIntArrayFromString(String string, int stringMaxLenght) {
    byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();   

    int rest = bytes.length % 4;
    int times = (bytes.length - rest) / 4;      

    int[] result = new int[stringMaxLenght];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        if (times > stringMaxLenght)
            break;
        int in = createIntFromBytes(bytes[i * 4 + 0], bytes[i * 4 + 1], bytes[i * 4 + 2],
                bytes[i * 4 + 3]);
        result[i] = in;
        maxIndex = i;
    }
    byte[] restb = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < rest; i++) {
        restb[i] = bytes[(maxIndex + 1 * 4) + i];
    }

    if (times < stringMaxLenght) {
        int lastInt = createIntFromBytes(restb);
        result[maxIndex + 1] = lastInt;
    }
    return result;
}

public static int createIntFromBytes(byte byte0, byte byte1, byte byte2, byte byte3) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
    byteArray[0] = byte0;
    byteArray[1] = byte1;
    byteArray[2] = byte2;
    byteArray[3] = byte3;
    return createIntFromBytes(byteArray);
}

public static String getStringFromIntegerArray(int[] intArray) {        
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(intArray.length * 4);
    for (int integer : intArray) {
        byte[] bs = createBytesFromInt(integer);
        buffer.put(bs);
    }
    return getStringFromBytes(buffer.array());
}

public static int createIntFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
}

public static String getStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    String string = new String(bytes);
    return string.trim();// otherwise it creates string with empty chars
}
```

but is seems not working for example string "Signature". Do you have any idea, what I am doing wrong, or how it should be done more nicely.

Comment: Without referring to the code, what would you *expect* the string "Signature" to come back as, in terms of an array of integers? Also note that calling `String.getBytes` without specifying an encoding is usually a bad idea, as it will use the platform default encoding.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do this? Because there are several methods and probably only one is fitting your problem.

Comment: you should first get the character of the string and then get the Integer corresponding to that char. The value of the Integer depends upon the encoding scheme of that you specify or platform default encoding.

Comment: To explain why I need this ugly stuff is simple. I need in my school project simulate memory (memory management is just an abstraction, not important in project). Because all memory operations except storing strings for my simple project is much easier (and faster) to store in integers than bytes I decided to simulate it as an integer array, where one integer represents one memory cell. So that's the point, no high goals :). Note: String.getBytes yes you are right it should be specified, in this example I just assumed UTF-8 encoding which is my project setting

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

    // From int[] to String
    String input = Arrays.toString(test);

    // Test
    System.out.println(input);

    // String back to int[]
    test = toIntArray(input);

    // Test
    input = Arrays.toString(test);
    System.out.println(input);

}

public static int[] toIntArray(String input) {
    String beforeSplit = input.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\s", "");
    String[] split = beforeSplit.split("\\,");
    int[] result = new int[split.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Result:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think I wasn't clear in question. The string was not like integeres, but normal letters so I can't use parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

```
How to convert String to Integer array and back in JAVA
```

Though the content of your question is not clear to me, assuming that you want to know if a built-in function available, to convert the `int` array to string you can make use of `Arrays.toString` function, for example:

```
  String strArr = Arrays.toString(new int[]{112, 12 ,13});
  System.out.println(strArr);
```

It will create following type of output format:

```
  [112, 12, 13]
```

Comment: I need the same functionality as String.getBytes() just for integers. It is for memory represented as int cells and I want to serialize string "Signature". Purpose is to write strings into memory and read it again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this row. There was a bad index offset.

wrong: **restb[i] = bytes[(maxIndex + 1 * 4) + i];**

good: **restb[i] = bytes[(maxIndex * 4) + i + 4];**

So it maybe helps somebody. This code is now working well.

```
public static int[] getIntArrayFromString(String string, int stringMaxLenght) {
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();   

int rest = bytes.length % 4;
int times = (bytes.length - rest) / 4;      

int[] result = new int[stringMaxLenght];
int maxIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    if (times > stringMaxLenght)
        break;
    int in = createIntFromBytes(bytes[i * 4 + 0], bytes[i * 4 + 1], bytes[i * 4 + 2],
            bytes[i * 4 + 3]);
    result[i] = in;
    maxIndex = i;
}
byte[] restb = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < rest; i++) {
    restb[i] = bytes[(maxIndex * 4) + i + 4];
}

if (times < stringMaxLenght) {
    int lastInt = createIntFromBytes(restb);
    result[maxIndex + 1] = lastInt;
}
return result;
 }

public static int createIntFromBytes(byte byte0, byte byte1, byte byte2, byte byte3) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
    byteArray[0] = byte0;
    byteArray[1] = byte1;
    byteArray[2] = byte2;
    byteArray[3] = byte3;
    return createIntFromBytes(byteArray);
}

public static String getStringFromIntegerArray(int[] intArray) {        
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(intArray.length * 4);
    for (int integer : intArray) {
        byte[] bs = createBytesFromInt(integer);
        buffer.put(bs);
    }
    return getStringFromBytes(buffer.array());
}

public static int createIntFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
}

public static String getStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    String string = new String(bytes);
    return string.trim();// otherwise it creates string with empty chars
}
```